# Windows egrep not matching regex

Tags: regex, cmd, grep

I'm trying to search a regex on windows after installing egrep.

This is an example of what I'm trying to find:

In the string below I want to match where ever it's comparing a single specific letter

```
if (lod_user.is_type == "A" || lod_user.is_type == "E" || lod_user.is_type == "S" || lod_user.is_type == "X")
```

so an acceptable result is `s_type == "A"` or `s_type == "S"`

and these are the queries I've attempted:

`"c:..\..\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\egrep.exe" -Hn --regexp=s_type[\s-]*==[\s-]*"[CUOMPSQDEXYAZ]" FILENAME`

The address to egrep, I will just refer to as egrep

`egrep -Hn --regexp=type[\s-]*==[\s-]*"[CUOMPSQDEXYAZ]" FILENAME`

`egrep -Hn --regexp=[\s-]*==[\s-]*"[CUOMPSQDEXYAZ]" FILENAME`

`egrep -Hn --regexp=[\s-]*==[\s-]*"A" FILENAME` just testing with one letter

`egrep -Hn --regexp=^type[\s-]*==[\s-]*"[CUOMPSQDEXYAZ]"$ FILENAME`

`egrep -Hn --regexp=^type$[\s-]*==[\s-]*"[CUOMPSQDEXYAZ]" FILENAME`

I'm not going to post all my attempts cause at some point I was just started playing around and guessing. This regex, `s_type[\s-]*==[\s-]*"[CUOMPSQDEXYAZ]"`, works on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ so I figured it has something to do cmd and problems with unescaped characters but i tried replacing quotes with `^"` for example but still nothing. This regexp works though `[\s-]*==[\s-]*"."` but doesn't accomplish what I want.

Answer (score 1):

`egrep` does not understand `\s`, try with the POSIX character class `[[:space:]]` in its place. Or if you really want to permit whitespace or a literal dash (minus) that would be `[-[:space:]]` where you have `[\s-]` currently. (Or are you trying to use Emacs character classes?)

Not sure about quoting rules on Windows, but traditionally, we quote the entire regular expression.

Comment: I had to look up the regex for spaces as I didn't remember what it was. If you quote the entire regex would quotes internal to the regex work or would I have to escape them? The spaces worked but I'm getting odd results such as `if(lod_deliverable.is_type == SSDeliverableTypes.ProjectAdmin)` for the query `--regexp=s_type[[:space:]]*==[[:space:]]*"[CUOMPSQDEXYAZ]"`  About to try with quotes around the entire regex EDIT: Still getting the same result

Answer (score 0):

The correct query is:

```
egrep -Hn --regexp="s_type[[:space:]]*==[[:space:]]*\"[CUOMPSQDEXYAZ]\"" FILENAME
```

Like tripleee said I needed to use [[:space:]] to represent the spaces for regex. I also had to quote the entire regex and then escape the quotes in the actual regex.